# JSON object is being broken by quotation mark

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm getting data from database via ajax call. After the ajax call I'm printing the data to the console like this:

Without JSON.stringify by `console.log(msg.users[i]);` the output is:

[image]

With JSON.stringify by `console.log(JSON.stringify(msg.users[i]));`

The output (JSON is **correct**):

```
{"kid_name":"Henryk","lying_down":false,"address_of_residence":null,"birthdate":null,"kid_last_name":"Kania","kid_id":1047,"group_name":"Klasa 0","group_id":243,"start_date":"2017-03-01","nazwa_diety":"Standardowa","extra_information":"","account":null,"kid_account":null,"diet_description":"","diet_school":217,"payment_day":1,"payments_hours":2,"card_numbers":null,"last_name":"Kania","name":"Henryk","id_kid":1047,"id_group":243,"activities_yearly_payments":false}
```

Then **directly after** printing this user to console I'm appending an element to the container like:

```
$('#container').append('<li data-kid='+JSON.stringify(msg.users[i])+'>Test</li>');
```

After appending this user into the data attribute the problem occurs - I don't know exactly what, but **something is breaking the JSON object and adds quotation mark** just after group_name field:

[image: Quotation mark which breaks the JSON]

Funny fact is that this problem does not occur for each user. Anyway JSON object logged into console is correct, so after appending element with the attribute everything should work well.

Comment: You don't need JSON.stringify to log JSON data or to put JSON data in a DOM element. Can you try the same without stringify? (a json string has quotes around properties, but a js object doesn't!)

Comment: But when I do remove the json stringify in the data-kid attribute I see following data: `data-kid="[object" object]`

Comment: @Kokodoko you might not need it to stringify to console log the data but you definitely do to store it in a (string) attribute of the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clean up the mess of quote-quoting by leveraging jQuery:

```
$('#container').append($("<li/>", {
  "data-kid": JSON.stringify(msg.users[i])
}));
```

That creates the `<li>` element and asks jQuery to set the `"data-kid"` attribute to your serialized object.

Comment: Thank you, in the final solution I'm creating elements with attribute via jQuery and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store that entire json inside an attribute you will need to escape all of the double quotes.

```js
var data = {"kid_name":"Henryk","lying_down":false,"address_of_residence":null,"birthdate":null,"kid_last_name":"Kania","kid_id":1047,"group_name":"Klasa 0","group_id":243,"start_date":"2017-03-01","nazwa_diety":"Standardowa","extra_information":"","account":null,"kid_account":null,"diet_description":"","diet_school":217,"payment_day":1,"payments_hours":2,"card_numbers":null,"last_name":"Kania","name":"Henryk","id_kid":1047,"id_group":243,"activities_yearly_payments":false}

var safeAttribute = JSON.stringify(data).replace(/"/g,'/"');
alert(safeAttribute);

$('#container').append('<li data-kid="'+safeAttribute+'">Test</li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="container"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're drawing a bare, unquoted attribute into the DOM, so it breaks after the first whitespace character (which the browser interprets as starting a new attribute). You need to wrap the attribute value in quotes and escape the double-quotes in the stringified JSON, or include a single-quote wrapper around the attribute itself (and escape any single quotes in the data), if you're drawing it directly into the DOM:

```js
var thedata = {"group_name":"Klasa 0"};

$('#container').append("<li data-kid='"+JSON.stringify(thedata)+"'>Test</li>");

console.log($('li').data("kid"))
console.log(JSON.stringify(thedata))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Alternatively, you can set the data attribute in jQuery, instead of drawing it into the DOM:

```js
var thedata = {"group_name":"Klasa 0"};

$('<li>Test</li>')
  .data("kid", JSON.stringify(thedata))
  .appendTo('#container');

console.log($('li').data("kid"))
console.log(JSON.stringify(thedata))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

That will take care of any quoting issues for you, but note that jQuery uses its own cache for `data` values; this will not set the attribute in the DOM itself. jQuery code will be able to access the data but anything which expects the attribute to be in the DOM will not see it.

Comment: When you *set* a `.data()` property with jQuery, the library does not update the element attributes. It will *appear* correctly that the data attribute is there via the `.data()` API, but no actual attribute will apear in the DOM or to another JavaScript framework.

Comment: True.  I'm assuming that they intend to read the data via jQuery because that's what's in the question, but that's worth pointing out in the answer; I'll update.

Answer (score -2):

I rebuiled your problem with [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19zmhLwq/2/) and can reproduce your issue.

From my personal view storing information on element attribute make no sense for me.

Thing over your data storage on browser or limit it to specific id or values.
Hold objects like json better on js context as on dom. And add references to dom objects if needed. Your are going over non-standard implementation that can cause problems or strange behavior.

Whats your usecase for holding json objects on element attr?

`var obj = {"kid_name":"Henryk","lying_down":false,"address_of_residence":null,"birthdate":null,"kid_last_name":"Kania","kid_id":1047,"group_name":"Klasa 0","group_id":243,"start_date":"2017-03-01","nazwa_diety":"Standardowa","extra_information":"","account":null,"kid_account":null,"diet_description":"","diet_school":217,"payment_day":1,"payments_hours":2,"card_numbers":null,"last_name":"Kania","name":"Henryk","id_kid":1047,"id_group":243,"activities_yearly_payments":false};
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
$('#demo').append('<li data-kid='+myJSON+'>Test</li>');
$("#out").append($("#demo li").attr("data-kid"));`

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.  Requests for clarification should be made as comments rather than as posted answers.